# adminer centos8 gibe me 403 forbidden with SElinux disabled

Tags: centos8

On CentOS i Install adminer to /usr/share/adminer

in /etc/httpd/conf.d/adminer.conf

```
Alias /adminer "/usr/share/adminer"
<Directory "/usr/share/adminer">
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymlinks
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.100
```

give me 403 forbiiden with SElinux disabled

Answer (score 0):

when I move adminer directory unde /var/www/html the page is corectly display